# How to permit users to view unpublished nodes which they didn't create?

Tags: nodes, users

I have created two roles: Editor and Reviewer.

Editor must only create unpublished nodes; instead, Reviewer must publish and view these nodes.

How can I make users with a role see unpublished nodes? If I set the permission "*Access the content overview page*", the users with that role can modify all contents and I don't want this.

I tried the [View unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module, but it has an issue, as reported in [View unpublished breaks access rules defined by Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2390703).

How to permit users to view unpublished nodes which they didn't create?

Comment: If somebody does not have role Editor and also not Reviewer, should it then yes or no be possible to "view" these nodes?

Comment: Role Editor must view only own unpublished node, instead Reviewer can view own unpublished node and any unpublished nodes of  the users belonging to Editor role.
If somebody does not have role Editor and also not Reviewer must view only published node.

Comment: Wow, that seems like another (new?) requirement that you added to your question now. Be careful about that, that's not something you're allowed to do in the same question, instead that might be like a followup (new) question (I'll try to enhance my answer later on, after you found a solution for the original question). But: you did not answer to my prior comment ... i.e. what "**if somebody does not have role Editor and also not have role Reviewer**"?

Comment: No, if somebody does not have role Editor and also not Reviewe must view only published nodes. In other words I want to do what makes the module "view_unpublished" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

I would "*set the permissions 'Access the content overview page'* ...", and combine that with using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to prevent "*the Reviewer can modify all contents*". Read on for more details about how to do so.

Create a rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module), that is a variation of the rule I included (in export format) in my answer to the question about "[How to restrict access to a node via node/12 and allow access via a path like content/sometitle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165114/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-node-via-node-12-and-allow-access-via-a-path-like-co/165126#165126)".

These are the changes to that rule to make it work for this case also:

- Append `/edit` at the end anywhere there is already something like `node/%` (I assume when somebody tries to edit a node, they use a node with  `/edit` at the end, though any variation of that should work in a similar way).
- Add a Rules '*Condition*' to verify that the current user trying to do such edit does NOT have role "Editor".
- You probably also need to add another Rules condition like "content is of type" (i.e. 'article' in your case, something that is not mentioned in your original question, but in an extra comment). That way the rules action does NOT apply for ay other content type.
- Change the "Message" (in the Rules '*Action*') to something that fits your needs.
- Modify the Rules '*Action*' to fit your own requirements, e.g. to issue a redirect to some other page.

Note that the Rules *Event* is "Drupal Is Initializing" ... Otherwise you are, for sure, "too late": you don't want the rule to be triggered after the edit session has been started already, instead it should be triggered before that. I.e when Drupal is getting ready to start an edit session.

Haven't experimented/tried creating this rule (= variation of the rule in the answer I mentioned above). But pretty sure it'll work.

You may also want to look at my answer to "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182958/how-to-limit-appearance-settings-based-on-roles-permissions/182959#182959" for another example of a rule, which uses some techniques similar to what you'd need here.

## Solution 2

*Solution 1* should work, but its weakness is that it's based on "Bypass Content Access Control". Personally I do not like that either. So I agree with your comment about that (a comment which has been removed via moderation). But hey, it's "a" solution to answer "your" (original) question.

If it was up to me to implement a "real" solution for the challenge you're trying to solve, I'd go for a plan b, as further detailed below.

Have a look at my answers to either of these questions:

- [How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601/how-to-implement-a-multi-step-approval-with-webforms-entityforms-based-on-form-c/164607#164607)
- [How can I allow anonymous visitors to submit content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164199/how-to-implement-content-suggestions-by-anonymous-users)

These answers explain how you can implement a workflow that is pretty (though not exactly) similar to what you are looking for.

To do so, it "only" requires you to use these modules (and regular content types):

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) (already suggested in the previous answer also).

And by using such approach, it does not require modules like "[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)" or "[Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench)" (modules that are typically involved for these kinds of workfows).

If you're not familiar with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework). And/or the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

**Note**: This "Solution 2" is also how I implemented a variation of your question on 1 of our own sites: it starts from an **Issue** (= problem or feature request), evolves to a **Recipe** (= instructions about how to get something to work) and ends with a **Software solution** (= a plugin or so, whereas the Recipe becomes part of the documentation). [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) and [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) do most of the work for this, and even works in D6 ...

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them for extended discussion, or other topics not related to the question.

Comment: Sorry ... But is it true that "comments cannot really be *removed*", and that they can only be "marked hidden for anybody except for moderators"? Also, is there a way to somehow restore those (crucial) comments that I referred to in the 1st paragraph within "Solution 2"? If not, how to adapt that paragraph so that it still makes sense if anybody ever wonders where that "Solution 2" came from  (which clearly deviates from the original question, but some of the deleted comments from OPer do explain that) ...

Comment: I just found this module https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished

Answer (score 2):

#### [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions **for each content type**. Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.

[image]

Comment: But If I grant the Editor to administer nodes, it can edit all content!
Or I do not understand how work this module.

I want that the Editor can view the unpublished node of other user by content type.

Comment: @kb8 you can do the screenshot settings for each content type. So for content type B, don't allow editor to edit any content.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/kTxXYMg.jpg) and [link](http://i.imgur.com/6LGX8CY.jpg)
@No Sssweat thank you

Comment: I not understand if this module allows the Editor role to view all unpublished node (own and not) only for a specific content type.

Comment: @kb8, After further investiation/testing Content Access does not have a view unpublished content permission. As per this article [Viewing unpublished content](https://www.drupal.org/node/1106606), `The only way to allow users access to all unpublished content in Drupal 7 (without using a contributed module), is to enable the permission 'Bypass content access control'.` which is no good for you, since they will be able to edit everything, even if content access module is enabled. So it looks like you need to use the [view_unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module.

Comment: thank you for help but I already tried view_unpublished but this has a [huge bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2390703). If I enable this module some views with unpublished content disappears for not admin user.

Comment: @kb8 it disappears for editors?

Comment: yes, if I enable the module, the Views with unpublished node (displayed on certain pages as blocks) disappear for all roles.

Comment: @kb8 by default, when you create a new view, view adds a filter of Content: Published (yes). [All you have to do it remove it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iEMyk.jpg) OR, edit it and select No to see all unpublished content only.

Comment: ↑ got it to work?

Comment: The Views breaks when I enable the module, before work without problems! The problem is that this module breaks some Views as you can read [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2390703) .

Comment: @kb8 even after [removing filter of Content: Published (yes)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iEMyk.jpg) ?

Comment: Yes, the Views are already with **Content Published** set to No

Comment: Tried to remove the all filter Content: Published (yes) but still not works.

Comment: @kb8 In your view, try with [changing the access to none](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9FFc.jpg)

Comment: @kb8 did you change [access to none](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9FFc.jpg)?

Comment: Content access is indeed part of the solution ... refer to my "solution 2" for details ... PS: you may want to integrate relevant comments in your actual answer (to avoid the risk they get deleted via moderation), especially for answers with "quite a few comments" ... like this answer ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unpublished_node_permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/unpublished_node_permissions) which creates granular permissions for each role which can be edited by an admin under `admin/people/permissions` to view unpublished nodes per content type.

It also takes care views permissions so for example `admin/content` view will filter nodes correctly as per the user's role permissions.

NOTE: there is a known bug with D8 multilingual sites and views that might create undersireable results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/access_unpublished. You do not need to worry about the role or even creating user. This module generate a hash key as query parameter along with node URL. You can also set lifetime of the hash key before it expires. You just need to pass this to the person whom you want to give access to. This is very useful in case of proofreaders.

Hope this is helpful for others too.