# Is there a way to add a Captcha to Ubercart?

Tags: ubercart, captcha

After some fraud attempts, I've been requested to add a Captcha to an Ubercart store in Drupal 7 and am surprised that in my searching I can't find any information on how to do this. Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about the add to cart form. Please share on what page or place you need captcha?

If you cannot find a module, then you need to do exactly what the captcha module does,

1. Write hook_fomr_FORM_ID_alter for the form for which you need to add the captcha.
2. Look for articles online explaining how to add captcha programmatically on a form in Drupal, ex: [How do I add reCaptcha to a custom form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101441/how-do-i-add-recaptcha-to-a-custom-form), https://www.drupal.org/node/743056.
3. Enable your custom module containing this code, and the captcha module.

You should have your captcha on ubercart's add to cart or any other form with a submit button.

Comment: Thanks -- working through with the person that requested it how much value a Captcha has on a multi-page checkout process but will accept this as the answer and may need to implement it pending outcome.